# How to upload a binary file in the body of an HTTPS request with NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, request

What I'm trying to do is:

1. get a signedUrl from Amazon (this works).
2. upload a file to
   amazon, using the signedUrl from point1.

   ```
   function uploadFileSilent(patientIdFromDb, fileName) {
       console.log("patientIdFromDb ", patientIdFromDb);
       console.log("FileName : ", fileName);

       var path = invokeUrl + '/prd/patient/' + patientIdFromDb + '/signeduploadurl';
       var data = '{fileName:"' + fileName + '",type:"eeg"}';
       var options = {};
       options.headers = { 'Authorization': token, 'Content-Type': 'application/json' };

       needle.post(path, data, options, function (err, resp) {
           if (err) {
               console.log("Error ", err)
           }
           else {
               console.log("resp : ", resp.body);
               var url = resp.body.signedUrl;
               var noProtocolUrl = url.replace("https://", '');
               var fileLocation = outputLocation + '' + outputFilename
               fileLocation = fileLocation.replace(/\\\\/g, '\\');

               var host = noProtocolUrl.substring(0, noProtocolUrl.indexOf('/'));
               var path = noProtocolUrl.substring(noProtocolUrl.indexOf('/'), noProtocolUrl.length);
               var FormData = require('form-data');
               var http = require("https");
               var form = new FormData();
               form.append('file', fs.createReadStream(fileLocation));

               var options = {
                   "method": "PUT",
                   "hostname": host,
                   "port": 443,
                   "path": path,
                   "headers": form.getHeaders()
               };
               var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
                   var chunks = [];
                   res.on("data", function (chunk) {
                       chunks.push(chunk);
                   });

                   res.on("end", function () {
                       var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
                       console.log(body.toString());
                   });
               });
               // Pipe form to request
               form.pipe(req);
           }
       });
   }
   ```

When the file post gets done, we receive the following error:

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

When we try the flow using Postman, it works. I think the issue could be that the file isn't passed to the body of the request.

Anyway, how to pass a binary file to the body of a PUT-request please?

Comment: I think there is issue with the content type. Try `Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream` . Also, pass `multipart : true` as shown here https://www.npmjs.com/package/needle#file-upload-using-multipart-passing-file-path

Comment: I think @MukeshSharma might be on to something - I had the same issue (literally postman worked, actual requests failed) and I found that I had simply mangled some strings in the head >_<

Comment: I've changed my code to this:

var options = {
                "method": "PUT",
                "hostname": host,
                "port": 443,
                "path": path,
                "multipart" : true,
                "headers": {
                    'content-type':'application/octet-stream'
                }
            };

and now I get: A header you provided implies functionality that is not implemented